# using explode with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing my project and I am using php and MySQL
My program is reading a data from textarea as a list of people, I use the explode function to separate the list and then I generate a for loop to insert them to MySQL database
till this part I don't have any problems
The problem is when I query the database with a where condition specifying a name from the list it does not recognize it
My question does the explode function change any thing to the names in the list or add any special characters
because I use the same functionality with specific name and it goes smoothly

Thanks in advance

Comment: Explode won't modify the content. Please provide your code

Answer (score 1):

It should not. PHP explode will not change your text and the WHERE query should operate correctly.

Are the characters all utf8 encoded? Check the database and see what you are querying for actually exists the same way you are sending it.

Like the others said, if you can provide us an example of the following it would be great:

1. Actual textarea input (not exploded).
2. DB Dump of what is inserted.
3. Your QUERY to select

Additionally, it could be a space issues, use trim before you insert the data or in your query instead of field = '$a' do a field LIKE '%$a%'

Comment: it is latin1_swedish_ci is that a problem...??

Comment: I am thinking more of the actual text added.

Comment: Please provide the above three items, this way I can see if there is anything wrong with the text (doesn't have to be exact text, just similar).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `explode()` will modify anything. try to use `trim()` in your foreach loop before inserting. Might be some characters that can not be seen.

Comment: yes it is viewing a single space after each name I don't know why...?

Comment: did you set your charset ?

Comment: like putting `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` in the `<head></head>` section. have you tried the `trim()` yet ?